# Web view Android

Tags: android

can we do gif animation in android web view.... i want to run some images step by step in continues way........

if this is possible then please tell how ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work the same way as in html. You just have to add a .gif animation to an `<img src="...">` and it should do the trick.